# Action bar title change on item selection - where?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android application and I have the standard list and details implemented with fragments. In case that only one pane is shown, I want to dynamically set the action bar title after transition depending on the selected item. Where should I do that?

I have already put the index of the selected item in the intent and forwarded it to the fragment, so both detail activity and detail fragment know about it. Logically, I would set the title in the fragment, otherwise I have to deal with my content in the activity. However, I also have to check whether I am in one or two pane mode which is done in the activity. So, where is the right place for updating the title?

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the title (and everything related to the content) belongs to the fragment. I was first thinking about using an interface for invoking an `updateTitle` method of the fragment from the activity. Because of the high complexity for such a simple thing, I rejected the idea. Instead, I check in the fragment whether a detail fragment is displayed, in order to know whether there are one or two panes on the screen. After that, I simply invoke `getActivity().setTitle(title)` from the fragment with my title as parameter. This seems to be much shorter.

I would still appreciate each answer telling me what is the best practice in respect to this. But for now, my problem is solved.